# Curl: Saving a file instead of opening it

Tags: php, file, curl, fopen, sugarcrm

I'm calling an API that sends me this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 06:30:16 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_mono/2.6.3 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.4.22 mod_perl/2.0.6 Perl/v5.8.8\r\n
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.22\r\n
Expires: \r\n
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private\r\n
Pragma: \r\n
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="LVDox-Master.docx"\r\n
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n
ETag: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\r\n
Content-Length: 68720\r\n
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n
\r\n
PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x000\x1FÎò¡\x01\x00\x00ß\x08\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml ¢\x04\x02( \x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
...
... (etc)
```

If I use this code the file is sent to the user and everything works fine:

```
list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result ,2);
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $header)
{
    header($header);
}

//return the nonheader data
return trim($content);
```

But now, I would like to save the file somewhere else so my script can work on it (rename it etc), so I don't want to directly send it to the user.

I've tried to comment the `header($header);` part, and do something like:

```
$content = getMyFile();
$file = fopen('MYTEST.docx', "w+");
fputs($file, $content);
fclose($file);
```

But the resulting file is not readable (it seems to be corrupted).

Do you have any idea of what could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the data write to the file location? ie, can you check the number of bytes written match what you expected, or is it not writing anything?

Comment: Yes I have a file with a size of 69KB. But this file is not correct (cannot open it). 
But if I keep the headers, everything works fine, but the file is sent to the user. 
So the headers might be important?

Comment: Try using `fwrite` instead of `fputs` - as you are dealing with a binary data.  Alternatively, why not just `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Same problem with fwrite and file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify content length for fputs for it to be binary safe.

In this case you could try `fputs($file, $content, 68720);`

And ultimately provide the length from the header.

Also I would suggest opening file in binary mode by using `fopen('MYTEST.docx', "wb");` especially in case you are running your code on Windows.